# Sharing same-version egg dependencies across different virtualenv environments in Python

Tags: python, virtualenv

Let's look at a sortof extreme case. Suppose you have 3 projects, A, B, C. And the package dependencies for those projects are:

proj A: `a-1.3` and `b-2.4`

proj B: `a-1.3` and `b-2.5`

proj C: `a-1.5` and `b-2.4`

With virtualenv, I have to create 3 environments for project and install their own versions of packages `a` and `b`. Instead of redundantly installed packages for each project, wouldn't it better to create 4 environment (for a-1.3, a-1.5, b-2.4, b-2.5, respectively) and load these environment in a modular fasion? For example, we can activate the environments a-1.3 and b-2.4 for project A.

Comment: What happens if you need to modify a-1.3 in project A? It will effect the other project as well...

Comment: Where's the question? Or the practical implication? You don't mean, that "wouldn't it better to create 4 environment...?" is the actual question?

Comment: @binarysmacker: I can see your point. I guess it's trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible or it would be somewhat difficult to have virtualenv environment to manage shared dependencies across environments.

However, there exist a heavier tool to manage Python package dependencies, [buildout](http://www.buildout.org/en/latest/). buildout has an `eggs-directory` feature where all downloaded Python eggs can be extracted and shared across different buildouts on the same local computer.

Create a `buildout.cfg` file for your project and have something like:

```
 [buildout]
 eggs-directory=/path/to/shared/eggs/folder
```

Alternatively you can set this on per-user basis by creating `~/.buildout/default` file.

Here is the [eggs-directory](https://github.com/plone/Installers-UnifiedInstaller/blob/4fc60bf5cd4877499575e375af23c07ec6c933f0/base_skeleton/base.cfg#L11) example as used in the installer of [Plone](http://plone.org).